# Coefficients of the $\cos(2^nx)$ expansion

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cos2x=2\cos^{2}x-1$$
$$\cos4x=8\cos^{4}x-8\cos^{2}x+1$$
$$\cos8x=128\cos^{8}x-256\cos^{6}x+160\cos^{4}x-32\cos^{2}x+1$$

Observing this identities I wondered what would be the coefficients of $\cos(2^nx)$ expansion?

$$\cos(2^nx)=\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}}a_{k}.\cos^{2k}x$$

Comment: $$\cos(mx)=2^{m-1}\cos^mx+\cdots$$

Comment: According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Explicit_expressions)
$$\cos(2^nx) = T_{2^n}(\cos x) = 2^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}} (-1)^k \frac{(2^n-k-1)!}{k!(2^n-2k)!}(2\cos x)^{2^n-2k}$$

Answer (score 2):

Look up the Chebyshev polynomials for a clue.